# How can I do validation and to get text from inputs with useForm?

Tags: reactjs

I want to do validation for my form before it will send to server, but I have a problem with useForm.

```js
const {
    register, handleSubmit, setError, formState: { errors, isValid }
} = useForm<loginFor>()
```

```js
const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<loginFor> = data => console.log(data);
```

My component where I try to do validation.
In my inputs I added  `{...register("password")}` and  `{...register("mailOrNumber")}`.
In my form I added `onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}`.
But when I write something in input and then I click on button with `type = submit` I see at console browser this:

```
{mailOrNumber: undefined, password: undefined}
```

Why `undefined`?
API documentation for react-hook-form suggests that it must work.

```js
return (
    <div className="popup-login">
        <div className="popup-login__cover-close-btn">
            <MyButton
                className="popup-login__close"
                type="button"
                onClick={changeStateForPopupClose}
            ></MyButton>
        </div>
        <div className="popup-login__main-cover">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                <div className="popup-login__cover-block">
                    <h2 className="popup-payment__title">
                        {
                            enterOrRegister === 'вход' ? "Вход в учетную запись" :
                                "Регистрация"
                        }
                    </h2>
                    <div className="popup-login__enter">
                        <MyInput
                            type="text"
                            className={inputClass.join(' ')}
                            placeholder="email или номер телефона"
                            {...register("mailOrNumber")}
                        />
                        <div className="popup-login__for-btn-show-hide">
                            <MyInput
                                type={!stateShowPassword ? "password" : "text"}
                                className={mailEnter.password.length ? "popup- 
                                    login__input popup-login__input_password hidden" : "popup- 
                                    login__input popup-login__input_password" }
                            placeholder =  "password"
                            {...register("password")}
                                />
                            {
                                mailEnter.password.length != 0 &&
                                <div
                                    className="popup-login__for-btn-show-hide_btn"
                                    onClick={showPassword}
                                >
                                    {!stateShowPassword ? "SHOW" : "HIDE"}
                                </div>
                            }
                        </div>
                        {
                            enterOrRegister === 'вход' && <MyCheckbox />
                        }
                    </div>
                    {enterOrRegister === 'вход' &&
                        <div className="popup-login__additional">
                            <h2 className="popup-login__titile-register">Нет аккаунта?
                            </h2>
                            <MyButton
                                className="popup-login__register"
                                type="button"
                                onClick={changeFormRegister}
                            >
                                зарегистрироваться
                            </MyButton>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
                <div className="popup-login__cover-btns">
                    <MyButton
                        className="popup-login__btn"
                        type="submit"
                    // onClick = {clickedOnEnter}
                    >
                        {
                            enterOrRegister === 'вход' ? "Войти" : "Зарегистрироваться"
                        }
                    </MyButton>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

inkredusk helped me and it's working.

Basically u need to pass as props from MyInput to  all things that are required.
like for example:

```
{...register("mailOrNumber")}
```

this is passed as

```
{..register("name")} directly on the <input> tag
```

I did like this:

```
  <MyInput
           type = "text"
           className = {inputClass.join(' ')}
           placeholder = "email или номер телефона"
           defaultValue = ''
           register = {{...register("mailOrNumber")}}
    />
```

Comment: Great work! Please do upvote if my answer has helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing the `name` attribute on your `MyInput` component. I am assuming here that inside the `MyInput` component you are using the `standard input` controls. You will need to pass the required `props` from your `MyInput` component to the underlying `input` fields. Can you please try something like this?

```
<MyInput
    type = "text"
    name = "mailOrNumber"
    className = {inputClass.join(' ')}
    placeholder = "email или номер телефона"
    {...register("mailOrNumber")}
/> 

<MyInput
  type ={!stateShowPassword ? "password" : "text"}
  name = "password"
  className = {mailEnter.password.length ? "popup- 
  login__input popup-login__input_password hidden" : "popup- 
  login__input popup-login__input_password" }
  placeholder =  "password"
  {...register("password")}
/>
```

**UPDATE**

As per the [React hooks form documentation](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started/#Registerfields) for registering fields, one of the key concepts in `React Hook Form` is to register your component into the hook. This will make its value `available` for both the `form validation and submission`.

**Note:** Each field is **required** to have a `name` as a key for the registration process.

Comment: If i write name, I see this:                                                                                                                            ```  TS2783: 'name' is specified more than once, so this usage will be overwritten.   ```                    Becourse here name is  password                                                                                                                ```  {...register("password")}```

Comment: please check this link - https://blog.logrocket.com/react-hook-form-complete-guide/

Comment: Does your `MyInput` component have a `name` property. ideally, if you have `input` then you need to mention `<input type="text" name = "password"/>` for the framework to identify. Can you post your code for `MyInput` component as well so it will easier to understand

Comment: I've seen at offical documentation https://react-hook-form.com/get-started/. At that link, you sent the information was publicated in the beggining of 2022. I think it's old yet), course at offical ocumentaition a little other

Comment: Ok  fine. However, can you try to post your code for `MyInput` component so that would be easier to understand. From the documentation, it is clear that you need to provide the `name` property

Comment: `    <MyInput
                  type = "text"
                  className = {inputClass.join(' ')}
                  placeholder = "email или номер телефона"
                   {...register("mailOrNumber")}  // here the name
         />                                                                                                                            
 `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253236/discussion-between-inkredusk-and--).